# How do I create a script that does a continous ping?

Tags: windows, python-2.7

The output initially is:
Reply from 
Reply from 
Reply from 
Then I'll get, when the connection is lost:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
When it's reconnected the response is:
Reply from 
Reply from 
Reply from 
Then I proceed to open a telnet session to my system and run python code.
When I use our utility I get this error below:
    def fin():

> ```
>   tb_session.close_connection()
> ```

conftest.py:38:

---

Comment: Maybe I didn't clearly state the problem:

When response is "Reply from":
 Assert the system is not down yet. (this could take 4 minutes)
if response is "Request timed out".
 Assert the system has rebooted. (this could take 4 minutes)
When the system comes backup again the response is "Reply from":
Assert the system has is backup.
After two "Reply from", break and goto the next command.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import subprocess
import re

bFlag = True
while bFlag == True:
    a = subprocess.check_output('ping 127.0.0.1')
    b = a.split('\n')

    iReply = 0
    for line in b:
        print line
        if re.search("Reply", line) == None:
            pass
        else:
            iReply+=1

    if iReply == 4:
        print "Total replies are 4"
    else:
        print "Ping broken"
        bFlag = False
```

Comment: Added a small script which you can run, you can change the ip and derive the IP from outside.